# Tor encryption: RSA or AES or else

Tags: aes, rsa, tor

I would like to know which part does the RSA 1024 or AES 256 used inside tor?

Because I found many post saying about RSA or AES when discussing tor.

whenever I look for how tor works, I got the answer like it encrypted 3 times each layers, and decrypt once each node.

I want to know how it encrypt and what is the thing it encrypt in a real tor network.

A really simple example is fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

FYI tor.stackexchange is a better place for this.  Also a warning, I know just enough to be dangerous :)

See https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/tor-spec.txt section 0.3.

> For a stream cipher, unless otherwise specified, we use 128-bit AES in counter mode, with an IV of all 0 bytes.  (We also require AES256.)
>
> For a public-key cipher, unless otherwise specified, we use RSA with 1024-bit keys and a fixed exponent of 65537.  We use OAEP-MGF1 padding, with SHA-1 as its digest function.

v2 [hidden services](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/rend-spec-v2.txt) identity keys were RSA-1024, but the newer [v3 onion services](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/rend-spec-v3.txt) public keys use ed25519.

Every Tor relay's long term signing-only identity key is RSA-1024.  Medium-term ntor "Onion Keys" are Curve25519.  Long-term "master identity" keys (which never change for a given relay) are Ed25519.

The tor-spec document also describes the encryption that can be used for connections between two relays in section 2 (Connections):

> Connections between two Tor relays, or between a client and a relay, use TLS/SSLv3 for link authentication and encryption.  All implementations MUST support the SSLv3 ciphersuite "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA" if it is available. They SHOULD support better ciphersuites if available.

Section 2.1 goes on to say about picking TLS ciphersuites...

> Clients SHOULD send a ciphersuite list chosen to emulate some popular web browser or other program common on the internet.

Because OpenSSL is used behind the scenes, all kinds of cipher suites are supported including things like `TLS1_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA` and `TLS1_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA`.

The materials in https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/ will answer all of your questions.